# botão submit não mostra que foi clicado

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Tenho a página abaixo:

***http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/contato.php***

Nela tem um **formulário** de **e-mail** e, logicamente, um **botão enviar**.

Porém esse botão enviar está recebendo um `return false` poque está enviando uma requisição ao **jQuery Ajax** para realizar ações na base de dados.

Mas esse `return true` não faz o efeito de mexer com o botão e então o usuário tem a sensação de que o **formulário** ***NÃO*** foi enviado e fica **clicando** várias vezes.

Gostaria de ajuda para fazer 3 coisas.

- Fazer um efeito tipo de que o botão recebeu o clique.
- Bloquear o botão até que a requisição seja completada.
- Colocar uma imagem **loading** enquanto a requisição esteja sendo **processada**

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#assunto").change(function () {
  if(this.value == 4) {
     $(".qual").css("display", "block");
     $("#qual").prop("required",true);
  } else {
     $(".qual").css("display", "none");
     $("#qual").prop("required",false);
  }   
  })


  $("div.contato form#formContato").on("submit", function () {

    if ($("div.contato form#formContato input[type=text].telefone").val().length > 0) {
  if ($("div.contato form#formContato input[type=text].telefone").val().length < 14) {
   alert("telefone ou celular precisam ser preenchidos com ddd + numero completo");
   $("div.contato form#formContato input[type=text].telefone").focus();
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 if($('div.contato form#formContato #assunto').val() == 4) {
  $('div.contato form#formContato #qual').val() = "";
 }
 
 if($('div.contato form#formContato #descricao').val() == "")   {     //verifica apena o texto
  alert("Descrição não está preenchida!");
  $('div.contato form#formContato #descricao').focus();
    return false;
 } 

   $.post ("_requeridos/email.php", {
    
    nome      : $("#nome").val(),
    email     : $("#email").val(),
    telefone  : $("#telefone").val(),
    descricao : $("#descricao").val(),
    assunto   : $("#assunto").val(),
    qual      : $("#qual").val(),
    
   }, function(retorno){

        if (retorno == "OK") {
          resposta = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
        } else {
          resposta = "Erro no envio do E-mail";
        }
       $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
       $(".resposta").html(resposta);     
            
     }
    );
  
    return false;
 
  }); 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<h1 class="titulos">Fale Conosco</h1>

<form class="formularios" id="formContato"> 
 
  <div class="contatoEsquerdo">  

    <label class="labelPequeno" >Assunto</label><select class="typeTextMedio" id="assunto" name="assunto" required>
      <option value="">Escolha o assunto</option>
      <option value="1">Orçamento</option>
      <option value="2">Indicação</option>
      <option value="3">Elogio</option>
      <option value="4">Outro</option>
    </select><br /><br />
  
    <div class="qual" style="display:none">
        <label class="labelPequeno" >Qual?</label><input type="text" class="typeTextMedio" maxlength="200" id="qual" name="qual" placeholder="Qual?" /> <br /> <br />        
    </div>
    
    <label class="labelPequeno" >Nome</label><input type="text" class="typeTextMedio" maxlength="200" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" required /> <br /> <br />
      
      <label class="labelPequeno" >Telefone</label><input type="text" class="typeTextMedio telefone" id="telefone" name="telefone" maxlength="15" placeholder="ddd + número"  /> <br /> <br />
  
    <label class="labelPequeno" >Email</label><input type="email" class="typeTextMedio" maxlength="200" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />

  </div>     
  
  <div class="contatoDireito"> 
    <h1 class="titulos">Descrição</h1>
    <textarea class="textarea" name="descricao" id="descricao" cols="80" rows="15" required></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <div class="contatoBaixo"> 
    <input name="envia" class="btnAcesso" type="submit" value="Enviar" /> 
  </div>

  
</form>

<div class="resposta" ></div>
```

Comment: Coloque o código JS referente ao formulário na pergunta.

Comment: Bom resolvi apenas escondendo o botão ao clickar sobre ele e colocar um loader (figura) no lugar do botão enquanto  a requisição é processada. Após isso, escondo o loader e volto o botão. Foi mais fácil

Answer (score 1):

Comece adicionando o um efeito hover no css

```js
$(".btnAcesso").click(function(event){
            $(event.target).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             $(event.target).after('<div class="loading">Carregando...</div>');
});
```

```css
   .btnAcesso:hover {
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contatoBaixo"> 
    <input name="envia" class="btnAcesso" type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
 </div>
```

Eu não consigo te ajudar com mais precisão porque não da pra testar aqui, mas você tem que fazer isso e quando a requisição retornar true, você habilita o botão de novo e tira o "Carregando..." com esses comandos:

```
$(event.target).removeAttr('disabled');
$('.loading').addClass('hide');
```

adicione também essa classe no seu css:

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```